# How can I show only the city name in a geo autocomplete input after a place is selected?

Tags: jquery, google-geocoding-api

Using jQuery Geocoding and Places Autocomplete Plugin is there a way to only show city name (not state or country) when I select a result from the suggestions list?

Comment: Razvan, have you had a chance to try out my answer?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not responding to you faster. It worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to only show a portion of the geocoded result after it's chosen from the autocomplete dropdown.

What you need to do is add a listener for the `place_changed` event, then trigger a "blur" and set whatever content you want the input box to display.

This should get you started:

```
function init(){
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        // make sure we pass the HTML element and not the jquery object
        $('#my-input-field')[0]
        ,{
            types: ['geocode']
        }
    );

    // When the user selects an address from the dropdown,
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
        var parts = [], 
            city_name = '';

        // convert the address to something more usable
        $.each(place.address_components, function (i, value) {
            parts[value.types[0]] = value;
        });
        city_name = parts.locality ? parts.locality.long_name : '';

        $('#my-input-field')
            .one('blur', function(){
                // and here's where we set the input to whatever value we'd like
                $(this).val(city_name);
            })
            .trigger('blur');
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi hberg, this works, thanks a lot! But one can see the transition from the selected value to just the city name when the code kicks in. Is it possible to prevent populating the input field with the selected value in the first place and then populating it manually with the desired value? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to hear that! I've had the same issue on my own site when using the plugin and haven't gotten around to resolving it. Google's autocomplete plugin actually pre-fills the input field with the whole address match and this method just quickly replaces it. You'd have to somehow intercept the other plugin to prevent it from setting the input field values. Wanna set up a jsFiddle to play around with it?